# Is it possible to handle Global Listeners Async using Wisper?

Tags: wisper

I am looking at implementing Wisper into an existing Rails application... I have been running the examples as a POC and I don't see a way to set up Events to be asynchronous when setting up listeners globally.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
Wisper.subscribe(MyListener.new, async: true)
```